# Parse Bloomberg API response to JSON in python3

Tags: json, python-3.x, bloomberg

How can I convert  the response message that returned from using bloomberg API in (python3 and flask) in to JSON

```
here is a response example:

ReferenceDataResponse = {
    securityData[] = {
        securityData = {
            security = "FB EQUITY"
            eidData[] = {
            }
            fieldExceptions[] = {
            }
            sequenceNumber = 0
            fieldData = {
                PX_LAST = 186.270000
                VOLUME = 16746904.000000
            }
        }
        securityData = {
            security = "IBM EQUITY"
            eidData[] = {
            }
            fieldExceptions[] = {
            }
            sequenceNumber = 1
            fieldData = {
                PX_LAST = 134.400000
                VOLUME = 2551009.000000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

dealing with it with the comming piece of code :

```
if str(msg.messageType()) == "ReferenceDataResponse":

    securities = msg.getElement('securityData')
    securities_count = securities.numValues()

    for i in range(securities_count):
        security = securities.getValueAsElement(i)
        ticker = security.getElementAsString('security')
       
        if (security.hasElement('fieldData')):
            fields = security.getElement('fieldData')
            fields_count = fields.numElements()
            for j in range (fields_count):
                
                security_dict = None
                field = fields.getElement(j)
                
                f_name = field.name()
                f_value = field.getValueAsString()
              
                security_dict = {"ticker":ticker ,"f_name":f_name , "f_value":f_value}
                bloom_data.append(security_dict)
```

give me (Object of type Name is not JSON serializable)
now, I cant not access the name object to reach the name of the fields
any help will be very appreciated

Comment: Bloomberg messages are NOT using json format. So you need to parse the message (multiple examples can be found online or in the docs) and create a JSON object from the data.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with python (I use the Java API). Based on the error message, I suspect the problem is `f_name = field.name()` which returns a `Name` object and not a string. In Java, you would do `field.name().toString()` to get the underlying string - I suppose there is a similar function in Python.

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of search I found this doc that is very helpful for as a schema for using the bloomberg api for dealing with the response ....

Here's the link ==>  [api schema](https://data.bloomberglp.com/labs/sites/2/2014/07/blpapi-developers-guide-2.54.pdf)

example for handeling respnse using python3:

```
bloom_data = []
if str(msg.messageType()) == "ReferenceDataResponse":

    securities = msg.getElement('securityData')
    securities_count = securities.numValues()

    for i in range(securities_count):
        security = securities.getValueAsElement(i)
        ticker = security.getElementAsString('security')

        if (security.hasElement('fieldData')):
            fields = security.getElement('fieldData')
            fields_count = fields.numElements()
            for j in range (fields_count):

                security_dict = None
                field = fields.getElement(j)

                f_name = field.name()
                f_value = field.getValueAsString()

                security_dict = {"ticker":ticker ,"f_name":str(f_name) , "f_value":f_value}
                bloom_data.append(security_dict)
```

Comment: for chainrefs use

`chainrefs = [w for v in field.values() for e in v.elements() for w in e.values()]`